# Why are doctrine fixtures getting progressively slower over time?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to stress-test some things in a symfony application. For that reason I want to load a rather big amount of dummy data into the DB.

My fixture's load-function looks like this:

```
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 1000000; $i++) {
            
            [... init entity ...]
            
            $manager->persist($work);

            if ($i % 800 === 0) {
                var_dump("records done: ".$i);
                $manager->flush();
                $manager->clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

I played around with different batch-sizes (somewhere between 50 and 10000) before flushing and clearing but it doesn't change the general picture that the processing time needed for the individual batches starts to increase bit by bit. In the beginning it's around 4 seconds per 1000 entities but before even half of the 1000000 entities are written to the DB its already at above 10 seconds per 1000 entities.

Why is that the case?
I thought with flushing and clearing the needed execution time per batch wouldn't degenerate significantly.
Are there further options to speed this up?

Comment: In fact, since the generated data is random, it can take more time at one moment than another without any reason ;)

Comment: Actually it is not random...the only thing that varies between the entities is their UUID and maybe some time-stamp. All other properties have the exact same values. And it is definitely the case that there is a trend that goes beyond usually to expect variations by outer circumstances.